# How to write case class for varying no of columns for DataFrames

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to write a case class dynamically for varying number of columns, data-type of the columns can be String.

Now I'm using RDD without any schema but I would like to use dataframes which needs schema.

Code Im using to fetch Headers from Databases

```
  var options = Map(
    "url" -> url,
    "driver" -> databaseRead.split(",")(4),
    "dbtable" -> databaseRead.split(",")(2),
    "user" -> databaseRead.split(",")(5),
    "password" -> databaseRead.split(",")(6))


 val fieldname = spark.read.options(options).jdbc(options("url"), options("dbtable"), new java.util.Properties()).schema.fieldNames.toArray
```

Comment: do you have header line in the data you are using for RDD? And it would be helpful if you share what you've tried so far

Comment: I remove headers from the file if it is a csv or I use above method for fetching headers from database.

Comment: why would you need case class when you have a schema?

Comment: How can we do without schema, is there any examples

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, Any help on this please..!